# fp-ts Option, Typescript and undefined

Tags: reactjs, typescript, undefined, option-type, fp-ts

I'm trying to create a simple helper function using `fp-ts/Option` and **Typescript** that takes a an **arbitrary** value and returns it as an `Option<T>`.

```
export const toOption = <T>(val: T): Option<T> => {
  return fromNullable(val);
};
```

The problem I'm having is, that no matter what I do, it includes undefined in the option.
In `somefile.tsx`
I have an object whose key value uses the `toOption` function. I need for that value to be an Option **only** but instead it reads the type as `(property) airDate: Option<(string & Date) | undefined>`

```
{
airDate:toOption(attributes.airDate), // (property) airDate: Option<(string & Date) | undefined>
}
```

Using type-guards

```
export const toOption = <T>(val: T): Option<T> => {
  if(typeof val == undefined) return none;
  return fromNullable(val);
};
```

Ternary

```
export const toOption = <T>(val: T): Option<T> => {
  return val ? some(val) : none;
};
```

Conditional

```
export const toOption = <T>(val: T): Option<T> => {
  if(!val) return none;
  return some(val)
};
```

They all yield the same type in the end: `(property) airDate: Option<(string & Date) | undefined>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The typescript utility type [`NonNullable`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#nonnullabletype) comes in handy at times like this.

```
export const toOption = <T>(val: T): Option<NonNullable<T>> => {
  return fromNullable(val);
};
```

But notice that there are no different between `toOption` and `fromNullable`, so if you want to use the name `toOption`, you could just assign the function as a value to `toOption` variable/const

```
export const toOption = fromNullable
```

You don't need to annotate the type because `fromNullable`'s signature already is `<A>(a: A) => Option<NonNullable<A>>`

Comment: This should be marked correct. Especially the last part. OP has just created an alias for `fromNullable`.

Comment: Revisiting my post from 7 months ago. Now realizing how silly it was at the time. But, I marked the answer correct, kudos for taking my silly question and also providing new clarifying information. I didn't know about the NonNullable type in TS.